# Python-Twitter API GetLocation

Tags: python, twitter

I am trying to get the location information from Twitter profiles using the python-twitter API (http://code.google.com/p/python-twitter/). The documentation (http://static.unto.net/python-twitter/0.5/doc/twitter.html) states that there is a GetLocation call, but I can't seem to get it to work.

Answer (score 2):

With the [Twython Library](https://github.com/ryanmcgrath/twython) you can get the location information for a user with a specific user name as follows:

```
from twython import Twython
twitter = Twython(APP_KEY, APP_SECRET,OAUTH_TOKEN, OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET)
print twitter.show_user(screen_name=USER_NAME)["location"]
```

It should be similar for other libraries.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

python-twitter is up to version 1.9, you're using ancient documentation! Since python-twitter is an exact mapping to the Twitter API, see the [Twitter docs](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1#103) if you want to get location info.

Comment: Haha thanks for pointing that out! Do you have a recommendation on how I can pull location data using the twitter api?

Comment: You could try a GET request on users/search and enter a location as your search query. If you want, you can also GET search/tweets by geocode.